# SIrange typeset different in text and math mode

Tags: siunitx

I observe a difference in the dashes typesetting when using `SIrange` in text or math modes. Any idea of why this happens?
Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
    range-phrase= -}

\begin{document}
    \SIrange{e-12}{e-10}{\second}
    $\SIrange{e-12}{e-10}{\second}$
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I think the character inserted `-` is interpreted differently in relation to the environment, so to obtain the same you could substitute the `-` to `\textendash`, or leave a conditional (more complicated)

Comment: Great! Works fine, but the unbreakable space before and after the dash disappear. So one needs to write 
`\sisetup{range-phrase= ~\endash~}` to be consistent with the typography rules.

Comment: Your answer is right, now that is protected the spacing results equally distributed with `sisetup{range-phrase= ~\texendash~}`. Feel free to accept the answer if it has solved your issues.

Comment: All good for me. Thanks to all of you for your -so damn quick- answers!

Comment: Technical reasons and answers aside, I'd use `(from) <first val> to <second val>` in (running) text (or similar construction) and `<first val> \cdots <second val>` in math-mode so that the endash (or even your actual minus sign) doesn't get confused with a subtraction. Typographically, an en-dash *without* space around it is correct.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel: again, my bad, mwe doesn't include the fact the document is in French, in which case en-dash without space is not correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As written in my comment, you can tell `LaTeX` to behave differently if you are inside or outside the math mode using the `TeX` command `\if<>\else<>\fi`; specifically using the conditional form:

```
\ifmmode<expression inside math>
\else
 <expression outside math>
\fi
```

So if this code is applied to your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{range-phrase=%
 \ifmmode\mathbin{-}
 \else
  \thinspace\textendash\thinspace
 \fi%
}
%
\begin{document}
%
\centering
\SIrange{e-12}{e-10}{\second}
\[
\SIrange{e-12}{e-10}{\second}
\]
%
\end{document}
```

The result is:

> [image: Result of the MWE with two identical outputs]

---

### Update

There is another way of having the correct dash, as egreg suggested, by considering the inclusion of text inside the math mode, replacing `\mathbin{-}` with:

```
\sisetup{range-phrase=%
 \ifmmode\text{\,\textendash\,}
 \else
  \thinspace\textendash\thinspace
 \fi%
}
%
```

Obtaining:

> [image: Result of the MWE with two identical outputs, visually identical to the earlier one]

Comment: Why not \sisetup{range-phrase=\ensuremath{-}}?

Comment: +1 for the diagnosis, but I wouldn't use `\mathbin{-}` in math mode (by the way, `\mathbin` is superfluous); maybe `\text{\textendash}` is better. If you add `\thinspace` on one side, it should be also on the other.

Comment: @egreg, noticed that if one has to be coherent, then it has to do it on both sides, I'll have to edit now. Ah... using `\text{\textendash}`, as I tried, gives no space between the numbers, so should I add this scenario to my answer (for the sake of completeness)?

Comment: `\text{\,\textendash\,}`, if you want to add a thin space on both sides. The OP's problem is exactly that one gets different typesetting and with your proposed solution the result is different.

Comment: @egreg All right, I'll make an addendum...

Answer (score 13):

The range commands (`\numrange` and `\SIrange`)  are only intended for use in text mode: this is covered in the documentation. The reason is that it's not possible to ensure in all cases that spaces are correctly dropped at the end of a line if you start off in math mode, so for example

```
$\SIrange{10}{20}$
```

would have the wrong spacing with the standard settings if the line break occurs at the `to`. As such, the code does not attempt to handle the case where it is used in math mode. I guess I can add a warning for this situation.

Comment: but a hyphen, as shown in the question for text mode, isn't really correct; the "connector" should be an en-dash.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Well that's down to the input chosen by the person asking the question: you need `range-phrase = --` to get an en-dash as always in TeX. Of course, the default is ' `to` ' as an en-dash looks very much like a minus sign.

Comment: thanks -- i overlooked the `range-phrase` input.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: The fact is that the context in which it really is used needs the math-mode for correct spacing (`$\tau_{32}=\SIrange{e-15}{e-11}{\second}$`); without having to explicitely add the spaces (what is the use of LaTeX then).

Comment: So the solution to this problem is to generally end the math environment before giving a range, i.e. `$\gamma =$ \numrange{1}{2}` ? A warning for ranges inside math mode would be good.

Comment: I'd like that warning, too. I have spent quite some time now trying to figure out why `\numrange` behaves weird in math mode (yes, I could have read the doc). As an alternative, what about you making range commands exit math mode, if necessary, and reentering it again? Would that work?

Comment: @bers There's no good, reliable way to do it and allow a line break (I have though about it): from math mode we can do `\hbox` but that's not good. I have an experimental version of the `siunitx` code I'm working on that should offer a way out, but I need to get everything working. It's a radical re-write so non-trivial!